# How would I delete items from a list with a button inside that list?

Tags: arrays, list, swiftui

SwiftUI
[This is the code for the list and my button]

```
ForEach(items, id: \.self) { current in 
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("\(current.task)")
                        .padding(2)
                    Text("\(dateFormatter.string(from: current.date))")
                    Button(action: {}, 
                           label: {
                                    Image(systemName: 
                                      "checkmark.rectangle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 35)
                           }) 
}
```

Items is my array containing a string and a date. Here is the code for it:

```
@State var items:[Tasks] = [Tasks(task: "Test", date: Date())]
```

And here is Tasks:

```
struct Tasks: Hashable {
  let task: String
  let date: Date 
}
```

[This is my list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd705.jpg)

I want to have a user be able to click a button under each list item and it will remove that list item. I am currently using the onDelete method but I would prefer to have a confirm button in each list item that would allow the user to remove that list item.

```
    @State var counter = -1
```

I tried using a counter that would increase by 1 each time the ForEach loop ran and create a new variable inside of that ForEach loop equal to it. However I could not access the variable inside of the button to use as an index.

Comment: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): posting a picture fo your code is not helpful. You should post text, that we can select and test. And it must be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - how do we know what is `items` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your current code structure, assuming each `task: String` is unique, you could just add this to your `Button` action:

```
 Button(action: {
     if let index = items.firstIndex(where: {$0.task == current.task}) {
         items.remove(at: index)
     }
 },
        label: {
     Image(systemName: "checkmark.rectangle.fill")
         .resizable()
         .frame(width: 50, height: 35)
 })
```

However, it would be more robust to add an `id` property to your `Task`, and
at the same time rename it, because Swift already defines `Task` as part of its async/await framework.

Here is the complete code I use to test my answer:

```
struct MyTask: Identifiable, Hashable { // <--- here
  let id = UUID() // <--- here
  let task: String
  let date: Date
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items:[MyTask] = [
        MyTask(task: "Test1", date: Date()),
        MyTask(task: "Test2", date: Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*44)),
        MyTask(task: "Test3", date: Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*88))
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(items) { current in     // <--- here
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(current.task).padding(2)  // <--- here
                Text(dateFormatter.string(from: current.date))  // <--- here
                Button(action: {
                    // --- here
                    if let index = items.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == current.id}) {
                        items.remove(at: index)
                    }
                },
                       label: {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.rectangle.fill").resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 35)
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let frmt = DateFormatter()
        frmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MMM-dd"
        return frmt
    }()
}
```